# Having other blogs content on my wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I Have stumbled across CNN's website today http://edition.cnn.com/TECH/ they seem to have several other blogs content on their blog from mashable and wired. I would imagine this is automated. I was wondering any one was aware of how to do this it looks like they are using Wordpress as their blogging platform.

Thanks

Ash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a RSS feed to pull in content from other blogs onto your blog. Have a look around on google there are loads of tutorials.

[Tutorials RSS Feeds into wordpress](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=rss+feed+into+wordpress&pbx=1&oq=rss+feed+into+word&aq=0&aqi=g3g-v1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1105l5824l0l6708l23l13l2l5l5l2l313l2796l0.6.6.1l20l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=9279c04e116fb7&biw=1440&bih=734)

[Also Read through this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed)

Comment: Cheers Matt this pointed me in the right direction ended up using FeedWordPress plugin Thanks